# Delete first lines after file append

Tags: php

I use append code to write new lines in .txt file:

```
$fh = fopen('ids.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fh, "Some ID\n");
fclose($fh);
```

I want this file to have only 20 lines and delete the first (old) ones.

Comment: unless those lines are EXACTLY the same size as the old ones, you'll have some work to figure out where they end, then slice them out of the file. this is not something you can do with a one-liner in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$content=file($filename);
$content[]='new line of content';
$content[]='another new line of content';
$file_content=array_slice($content,-20,20);
$file_content=implode("\n",$file_content);
file_put_contents($filename,$file_content);
```

You can us file() function to load file as an array. Then add new content to loaded array, slice it to 20 elements, make 'entered' text from this array and save it to a file.

Comment: No, don't load the whole file as an array. This is inefficient, and even won't work if the file is huge.

Comment: But this file will not be huge. It will always have max 20 lines.

Comment: If it is one-time-run script then time/resources doesn't have big meaning. Results are correct and this is the most important.
If it is a production environment then this script will be run frequently so the file will always be small.
If this script is the only user of this file there is no problem at all - there will be always max 20 lines in this file (because no other script writes to this file).

Answer (score 1):

Read all the lines in, add your lines at the bottom, then rewrite the file with only the last 20 lines.

Answer (score 1):

I am not great at php, but if you only want 20 lines surely you would do something like this pseudocode.

```
lines <- number of lines you want to write
if lines > 20
  yourfile <- new file
  yourfile.append (last 20 lines of your text)
else if lines = 20
  your file <- new file
  yourfile.append (your text)
else
  remainingtext <- the last [20-lines] of yourfile
  yourfile.append (remaining text + your text)
```

EDIT: an easier way of doing it, but perhaps less efficient [I think this is equivalent to NovaDenizen's solution]

```
yourfile <- your file
yourfile.append(yourtext)
newfilearray <- yourfile.tokenize(newline)(http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
yourfile <- newfile
for loop from i=newfilearray.size-21 < newfilearray.size
  yourfile.append (newfilearray[i])
```

Comment: Sounds like a decent solution, actually. You don't want to read in the whole file if it's 200GB (and if you're only keeping the final 20 lines). You do still have to line-scan it all, but at least you don't need to keep the entire contents.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the function `file`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

> Reads an entire file into an array.

This said, you Need to do the following:

1.) Read the existing file into an Array:

```
$myArray= file("PathToMyFile.txt");
```

2.) Reverse the Array, so the oldest Entry is topmost:

```
$myArray= array_reverse($myArray);
```

3.) Add your NEW Entry to the end of that Array.

```
$myArray[] = $newEntry + "\n";
```

4.) Reverse it again:

```
$myArray= array_reverse($myArray);
```

5.) Write the first 20 Lines back to your file (this is your "new" + 19 old lines):

```
$i = 1; 
$handle = fopen("PathToMyFile.txt", "w"); //w = create or start from bit 0
foreach ($myArray AS $line){
   fwrite($handle, $line); //line end is NOT removed by file();

   if ($i++ == 20){
     break;
   }
}
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you just use file_put_contents("yourfile.txt", ""); to set the file contents to nothing and then just file_put_contents("yourfile.txt",$newContent)?

Are you trying to do something else or am I missing something?

Comment: You forgot to keep the original final 20 lines. Also, if you _were_ simply replacing the file's contents, why would you do `""` first? When the second call does the same job anyway?

Comment: I do not see "keep the original final 20 lines" in his original question at all. This question should be re-worded for proper solutions to occur. Valid point btw about file_put_contents, Lightness Races in Orbit .

Comment: The requirements are trivially discernible from the question. `I want this file to have only 20 lines and delete the first (old) ones.` If the OP wanted to erase _all_ the lines from the original file, then there would only ever be 1 line, not 20.